# Database in two folder, bin->debug, release

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am adding  my database in both bin->Debug and bin->Release folder. 
When I create a setup file, I am getting the primary output from configuration manager->release. 
Is there a way I could have the DB set up at only one place (not both Debug and Release folder)
This is the connection string:

```
 <add name="myConnString" connectionString="Data Source=Test.sqlite; InitialCatalog = Test.sqlite;Compress=True;Version=3"
      providerName="System.Data.Sqlite" />
```

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a 'data' folder at the same level than the bin  folder? This way the database location never changes, and you can use **InitialCatalog =../../data/Test.sqlite**

Answer (score 0):

Place it in the main Project path:

```
<add name="myConnString" connectionString="Data Source=Test.sqlite; InitialCatalog = ..\..\Test.sqlite;Compress=True;Version=3"
  providerName="System.Data.Sqlite" />
```